# windows phone map auto zoom on double tap

Tags: bing-maps, windows-phone-7

I have my map declared in xaml like this:

```
<my:Map Height="497" CredentialsProvider="key" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,104,0,0" Name="map1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="450" ZoomBarVisibility="Visible" />
```

And I can't figure out why on double tap map is zoomed in? How can I disable this behavior?
Thanks in advance, best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default behavior of the map control. I can only think of two ways to disable this functionality:

1. Create a custom `MapControl` and override the map's `OnDoubleTap` or `OnZoomLevelChanged` methods
2. Listen to the map's `MapZoom` or `DoubleTap` event handlers and utilize `e.Handled = true` in cases that you don't want other handlers to do anything.

Hopefully this helps a little.